# How to write the Swift code for checking the users location and only carrying out the function if they are in the geofence radius?

Tags: swift

The goal is to only allow the data to be posted from tapping the "I'm Here" if the current users location is within the pre-defined geofence. If they are outside the bounds they will receive an alert error and the data will not be posted to the Firestore.

I've read about the didDetermineState but am having trouble understanding.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class checkInViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    @IBOutlet weak var imHereButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var callUsButton: UIButton!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        setUpElements()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        let geoFenceRegion:CLCircularRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(xxxx, xxxx), radius: 5, identifier: "xxxx")

        locationManager.startMonitoring(for: geoFenceRegion)

    }

    func setUpElements (){
        Utilities.styleFilledButton(imHereButton)
        Utilities.styleFilledButton(callUsButton)
    }

    @IBAction func backTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
        print("Check-In Enabled")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
        print("Check-In Disabled")
    }

    @IBAction func imHereTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

        guard let memberNumber = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "memberNumber"), !memberNumber.isEmpty else
        { return }
        guard let firstName = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "firstName"), !firstName.isEmpty else
        { return }
        guard let lastName = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "lastName"), !lastName.isEmpty else
        { return }

        let checkInData = ["name":"\(firstName) \(lastName)", "memberNumber":memberNumber, "userId": uid]

        FirestoreReferenceManager.myReferenceForCheckIn().addDocument(data: checkInData) { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                    print("Error, Data not saved")
                } else {
                self.showResAlert(title: "Welcome Back", message: "You are now CHECKED-IN please continue to the rental counter. Thank You.")
                }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func callUsTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(xxxx)"),
            UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
}

extension checkInViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate{

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    }

}
```

Comment: What does your code do thus far?

Comment: @halfer My "post" code posts the data to firestore however there is no "check if the device location is within geofence radius"